# Como definir o foco em uma div após a renderização?

Tags: react

Estou iniciando em React e acabei travando em uma parte do código.

Estou gerando dinamicamente alguns elementos html como `label` e `input` a partir do clique em um link.

Queria adicionar a funcionalidade de focar a div, quando o usuário clicar em cima da div que engloba esses elementos html fosse aplicado o estilo css dentro do `class=""` fazendo com que a borda da div ficasse com um destaque em vermelho para representar o clique do usuário em cima do elemento.

Tentei fazer algo com `useState` fazendo com que fosse gravado o class do elemento css, até que deu certo mas quando clico em cima do elemento todas as divs ficam com a estilização e no caso teria que ser só no elemento referente ao clique onde cada botão tem seu estado. Como resolver isso no React?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./../form/style.css";

export default function Form() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    numChildren: 0
  });
  const children = [];

  const [focus, setFocus] = useState("");

  const ChildComponent = (props) => (
    <div
      class={"form-container " + focus}
      onClick={() => {
        onFocus();
      }}
    >
      <label>{props.id} - Digite uma pergunta </label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  );

  for (var i = 0; i < state.numChildren; i += 1) {
    children.push(<ChildComponent key={i} id={i} />);
  }

  function onAddChild() {
    setState({
      numChildren: state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }

  function onFocus() {
    if (focus) {
      setFocus("");
    } else {
      setFocus("focusElement");
    }
  }

  const ParentComponent = (props) => (
    <div className="card calculator">
      <p>
        <a href="#" onClick={props.addChild}>
          Entrada de Texto
        </a>
      </p>
      <div id="children-pane">{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form">
        <ParentComponent addChild={onAddChild}>
          <div className="formPreview" id="formPreview">
            <div id="formGroup" className="formGroup">
              {children}
            </div>
          </div>
        </ParentComponent>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Css:

```
.focusElement {
  border: 1.8px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.form-container {
  background: rgb(236, 235, 235);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Exemplo no CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-vaughan-nqniy?file=/src/components/form/style.css:0-182)

Answer (score 0):

A idéia de construir aplicações com [react](/questions/tagged/react) é criar componente com seus estados. Um ideia de código é manter o estado de cada elemento como se fosse um `flag` se tem ou não `focus` e com isso ter controle em cada elemento (`<div>`) que foi clicado ou selecionado.

O exemplo proposto sugere que cada tarefa tem um `flag` de `focus` com o tipo verdadeiro ou falso (`boleano`) para guarda o estado de qual elemento foi selecionado por último retirando o elemento anterior que estava selecionado (se tiver algum elemento diferente desse que foi selecionado ou clicado).

```js
function App() {
  const [tarefas, setTarefas] = React.useState([
    {'id': 1, 'label': 'Tarefa 1', 'desc':'', 'focus': false},
    {'id': 2, 'label': 'Tarefa 2', 'desc':'', 'focus': false},
    {'id': 3, 'label': 'Tarefa 3', 'desc':'', 'focus': false}
  ]);
  function handleDivFocus(idx) {
    let _tarefas = tarefas.map(function(item, index) {
      if (index === idx) {
        return {...item, 'focus': true};
      }
      return (item.focus) 
          ? {...item, 'focus': false}
          : item;
    });
    setTarefas(_tarefas);
  }
  function handleDescChange(e, id) {
    let _tarefas = [...tarefas];
    const _index = _tarefas.findIndex(c => c.id === +id);
    if (_index >= 0) {
      _tarefas[_index].desc = e.target.value;
      setTarefas(_tarefas);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>      
      {tarefas && tarefas.map((tarefa, index) => (
        <div key={index} className={tarefa.focus?'form-container focusElement':'form-container notFocusElement'} onClick={e => handleDivFocus(index)}>
          <label>{tarefa.label}</label>
          <input type="text" value={tarefa.desc} onChange={e => handleDescChange(e, tarefa.id)} />
        </div>
      ))}      
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.focusElement {
  border: 1.8px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); 
}
.notFocusElement {
  border: 1.8px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); 
}
.form-container {
  background: rgb(236, 235, 235);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

***Bonus***: as caixas de texto tem o seu próprio estado dentro do `array` de tarefas, e para alterar o elemento que está sendo digitado precisa saber qual é o elemento e com isso alterar o seu valor, nesse caso identifica pelo `id` do elemento, busca seu índice ou posição do `array` e muda somente a sua descrição, mantendo os demais estado como estão.

Resumindo: todo elemento de tela que precisa de mudança de estado precisa ter um estado declarado e com ele manipular os elementos.